# how to catch form open event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two win forms frmMain and frmMemberSearch, there is a button in frmMemberSearch will run a function and execute the following code.

```
frmMain main = new frmMain(true, search_content, member_id);
main = (frmMain)Application.OpenForms["frmMain"];
```

this will switch back to frmMain, and how to catch this event for "OpenForms", I had used Shown but it doesn't work:

```
//constructor
public bool isDisplay = false;
public frmMain(bool isDisplay, string searchContent="", int member_id=0, int unit_id = 0) {
            InitializeComponent();
            Shown += frmMain_Shown;
}

private void frmMain_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
   if (this.isDisplay == true) {
      Messagebox.show("hello");
   }
}
```

What event should I use to track the event?

Answer (score 0):

You have to show the form to fire the event frmMain_Shown.
Try below

```
frmMain main = new frmMain(true, search_content, member_id);
main = (frmMain)Application.OpenForms["frmMain"];
main.ShowDialog();
```

Use `ShowDialog` or `Show` methods as per your requirement.